# Creating a mysql query syntax with JOINING tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, syntax

I'm having trouble getting some data.... I was wondering if someone can help me,

I have 4 tables (likes, follow, comment, users)

I want to be able to populate my page when a user likes/comments/follows/etc... (if a user is following a particular user).

**likes**

```
idlikes   idusers    iditem
  1          1          5
  2          2          4
  3          2          22
```

**follow**

```
idfollow   idusers_follower   idusers    idbusiness
  1              1               2           
  2              1               3           
  3              1               4           
  4              4               2           
  5              4                           1
```

**comment**

```
idcomments   idusers    text
   1            1       asfd
   2            2       safd
```

**users**

```
idusers
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

For example if I am id user #1, I'm following users #2, #3, #4

**My page would populate to show:**

- #2 likes item #4, #22.
- #4 is following #2 (because I'm following #4, this is why its showing)
- #2 comments "safd"

I'm not sure what is the best way to display this? I currently have multiple functions querying on table at a time, and I'm working on merging the arrays together? Or should I use join tables? Which I'm trying now...

Get users that I'm following.

```
$feeds = new feed();
$meID = 1;
$query = "SELECT idusers FROM follow WHERE iduserse_follower = ?";

$users = $dbh -> prepare($query);
$users -> execute(array($meID));

while($following = $users -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $follow = $following['idusers']; //This will get all of useres I'm following
      $populate = $feeds->feed_all($follow); // from function
}
```

**Query**

```
class feed()
{
     public function feed_all($idusers)
     {
         // SYNTAX HELP //////////////////////
           $query = "SELECT 
           f.idusers_follower, 
           f.idusers, 
           l.iditem, 
           c.text 
           FROM follow f, users u 
           JOIN likes l 
           ON l.idusers = f.idusers 
           JOIN comment c
           ON c.idusers = f.idusers
           WHERE f.idusers_follower = ? AND f.idusers_follower = l.idusers AND f.idusers_follower = c.idusers AND f.idusers = u.idusers"

           $pop = $dbh->prepare($query);
           $pop ->execute($idusers);

           // while loop to return value
    while($row = $pop -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $feed_data[]=$row;
    }
    return $feed_data;
     }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. :( I'm not even sure if I'm doing the statement right?

**++++++++++   EDIT:  ++++++++++++**

I have edited to add **idbusiness**

Now since I'm following #4, it would also show up that #4 is following #1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current approach of performing three separate queries is as good as any; you can combine them into a single resultset using [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html), which would be useful if you wanted to sort the combined results by some field (e.g. activity timestamp) and/or limit the combined results:

```sql
  SELECT idusers, 'likes' AS what, likes.iditem AS detail
  FROM   likes JOIN follow USING (idusers)
  WHERE  follow.idusers_follower = 1

UNION ALL

  SELECT f1.idusers, 'follows', f2.idusers
  FROM   follow f1 JOIN follow f2 ON f1.idusers = f2.idusers_follower
  WHERE  f1.idusers_follower = 1

UNION ALL

  SELECT idusers, 'commented', comment.text
  FROM   comment JOIN follow USING (idusers)
  WHERE  follow.idusers_follower = 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31cdb/1/0).

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me, I was wondering if its not too much trouble if you can show me how I can add 1 more table (I have edited to add `idbusiness` next to `idusers` in the `follow` table. In case #4 is following #1 (in the business table). Would I need another UNION ALL just to have idbusiness?

Comment: @andrewliu: It isn't clear to me what you wish to display in this case.

Comment: before I didn't have `idbusiness` column, it was just idusers in the follow table. But idbusiness is different than idusers, so if a user wanted to follow a business, instead of the user, it would show the idbusiness. But because the original code that you wrote, only shows idusers, it becomes empty if a user is following idbusiness. Example: since I'm following iduser #4, it will populate to show that #4 is following #2 (from idusers) and #1 (from idbusiness). Does this make sense? Sorry! and Thanks!

Comment: @andrewliu: What does it mean when `idbusiness` and `idusers` are both set in some record, vs each appearing where the other is `NULL`?

Comment: sorry, i deleted that one number that wasn't supposed to be there. so each row is supposed to be a new record. say if there's buttons, 1 for business and 1 for users. user (#4) will press follow business, so it will have a new record, and me (#1) would see that. Also, #4 has followed a user, I would see that also, because I'm following him. Everything works great, I was just wondering if the syntax is completely different with an added column? I hope this makes more sense? Thanks again!

Comment: @andrewliu: I'd use another `UNION`.